# Modernizr.prefixed (is not a function) in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I'm trying to get a script running on a cms page in Magneto. Console is responding with:

> Uncaught TypeError: Modernizr.prefixed is not a function

Strange as this script runs perfectly in normal html conditions...

Problem would be this line:

```
animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
```

The script (taken from codrops):

```
(function() {
var support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
        animEndEventNames = { 'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd', 'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd', 'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd', 'animation' : 'animationend' },
        animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
        onEndAnimation = function( el, callback ) {
            var onEndCallbackFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.animations ) {
                    if( ev.target != this ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
                }
                if( callback && typeof callback === 'function' ) { callback.call(); }
            };
            if( support.animations ) {
                el.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndCallbackFn();
            }
        };

    var containers = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.container' ) ),
        containersCount = containers.length,
        nav = document.querySelector( 'nav.thumb-nav' ),
        pageTriggers = [].slice.call( nav.children ),
        isAnimating = false, current = 0;

    function init() {
        resetScroll();
        // disable scrolling
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );
        // set current page trigger
        classie.add( pageTriggers[ current ], 'thumb-nav__item--current' );
        // set current container
        classie.add( containers[ current ], 'container--current' );
        // initialize events
        initEvents();
    }

    function initEvents() {
        // slideshow navigation
        pageTriggers.forEach( function( pageTrigger ) {
            pageTrigger.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                navigate( this );
            } );
        } );

        // open each container's content area when clicking on the respective trigger button
        containers.forEach( function( container ) {
            container.querySelector( 'button.trigger' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                toggleContent( container, this );
            } );
        } );

        // keyboard navigation events
        document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
            var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which,
                isContainerOpen = containers[ current ].getAttribute( 'data-open' ) == 'open';

            switch (keyCode) {
                // left key
                case 37:
                    if( current > 0 && !isContainerOpen ) {
                        navigate( pageTriggers[ current - 1 ] );
                    }
                    break;
                // right key
                case 39:
                    if( current < containersCount - 1 && !isContainerOpen ) {
                        navigate( pageTriggers[ current + 1 ] );
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } );
    }

    function navigate( pageTrigger ) {
        var oldcurrent = current,
            newcurrent = pageTriggers.indexOf( pageTrigger );

        if( isAnimating || oldcurrent === newcurrent ) return;
        isAnimating = true;

        // reset scroll
        allowScroll();
        resetScroll();
        preventScroll();

        var currentPageTrigger = pageTriggers[ current ],
            nextContainer = document.getElementById( pageTrigger.getAttribute( 'data-container' ) ),
            currentContainer = containers[ current ],
            dir = newcurrent > oldcurrent ? 'left' : 'right';

        classie.remove( currentPageTrigger, 'thumb-nav__item--current' );
        classie.add( pageTrigger, 'thumb-nav__item--current' );

        // update current
        current = newcurrent;

        // add animation classes
        classie.add( nextContainer, dir === 'left' ? 'container--animInRight' : 'container--animInLeft' );
        classie.add( currentContainer, dir === 'left' ? 'container--animOutLeft' : 'container--animOutRight' );

        onEndAnimation( currentContainer, function() {
            // clear animation classes
            classie.remove( currentContainer, dir === 'left' ? 'container--animOutLeft' : 'container--animOutRight' );
            classie.remove( nextContainer, dir === 'left' ? 'container--animInRight' : 'container--animInLeft' );

            // clear current class / set current class
            classie.remove( currentContainer, 'container--current' );
            classie.add( nextContainer, 'container--current' );

            isAnimating = false;
        } );
    }

    // show content section
    function toggleContent( container, trigger ) {
        if( classie.has( container, 'container--open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( container, 'container--open' );
            classie.remove( trigger, 'trigger--active' );
            classie.remove( nav, 'thumb-nav--hide' );
            container.setAttribute( 'data-open', '' );
            preventScroll();
        }
        else {
            classie.add( container, 'container--open' );
            classie.add( trigger, 'trigger--active' );
            classie.add( nav, 'thumb-nav--hide' );
            container.setAttribute( 'data-open', 'open' );
            allowScroll();
        }
    }

    // scroll functions
    function resetScroll() { document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; }
    function preventScroll() { window.addEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll ); }
    function allowScroll() { window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll ); }
    function noscroll() { 
        window.scrollTo( 0, 0 ); 
    }

    init();

    // For Demo purposes only (prevent jump on click)
    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.items-wrap a') ).forEach( function(el) { el.onclick = function() { return false; } } );
})();
```

I removed all Magento js and css from the cms page and replaced it with the demo files from Codrops. It just won't run...

What am I doing wrong (not being a buff with js)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like the Modernizr script hasn't loaded at the point it runs that line.

Comment: Been thru that. Replaced with a development built Modernizer with no effects. (in the codrops demo it took the whole function down)

Comment: To force Modernizr be loaded before the script does I combined them in a single script. Sadly that wasn't the solution... Any takers for this issue? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Javascript construct

```
(function() {
    //... all your code, including Modernizr.prefixed() call ...
})();
```

Is basically saying

> Hey Javascript, define an anonymous function, and then **immediately** call it

I'm not familiar with how `Modernizr` loads itself into the page, but based on what you're describing, your page is probably setup something like this.

```
//...
(function() {
    //... all your code, including Modernizr.prefixed() call ...
})();
//...

<script src="[path to include that defines global Modernizr object]"></script>
Modernizr
```

You'll need to investigate how your Magento system is loading `Modernizr`, and ensure your function definition/call comes **after** that.

Comment: It's a toughy. The setup of the page is just the other way around, so modernizer first followed by the function... I'll be digging in Magento loading. Thanks!

Comment: @MichelvM If that's the case then 1. Does Modernizr itself use some sort of delay/on body ready before loading?  2. Are you sure its the line in your anonymous function that causes the error and not another, similar line? 3. Can you temporarily place your anonymous function in a setTimeout with a delay of 1000 - 2000 to see if it fixes the error

Comment: Well... a few hours of plain panic and something mysterious... replaced JQuery 1.11.3 with the original 1.10.2 and tada... smooth as smooth can be. Beats me why and what. Will look into this AFTER this site is up and running. Thanks for both your time!!!